# Share memory between my application and application is running after inject dll

Tags: c#, c++, memory, hook, share

I build a application, when my application is building, It will inject dll into all applicaton is running, and I want to share memory between my applicaton and application is running. I want OpenFileMapping will automatic running when dll inject into applacation is running. But I don't know how do this?

Comment: "You" are injecting a DLL into foreign Windows processes, but don't know how to memory map a file? So.. from where did you download the DLL injection code?

Comment: no, in my applicaton I create createmappingfile and send data, but I don't know dll will openmappingfile successful and receive data. Sr for my english

Comment: hi, I inject dll into applicaton is running, but I don't know how inject dll successful, Can help me check inject dll successful ! I inject dll by Setwindowshookex! Thank :)